# WinAPI Combobox can't use number?

Tags: winapi

How to use Combobox use number?

I want use combobox number 1970~2021

This is my code

```
BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hCombo;
    TCHAR year[50];
    static int ComboSelection;
   

    switch(iMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        hCombo = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_COMBO_YEAR);
        ComboSelection = -1;

        for(int i=1970; i<=2021; i++)
        {
             year = i;
             SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)year);
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

HOW TO USE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year = i;`

This will not copy the integer to the string array.

`swprintf_s(year,50,L"%i",i);` instead.

Or better, use std::wstring.

Comment: "*Or better, use std::wstring*" - if you are using C++, that is. For example: `SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(std::to_wstring(i).c_str())); ...`.  If your ComboBox is using an ANSI window instead of a Unicode window, you can use `std::to_string()` instead.